# Can you screen save on a Nexus 4?

Tags: nexus-4, screenshots

I fly a lot, but never accept a mobile boarding pass as I need a decent signal to display it. My iPad allows me to save screenshots to the gallery. I find it incredibly usefull, but can't find it on my Nexus 4!!

Answer (score 0):

If by "screen save" you mean a screenshot, yes you can :)

Just press both <kbd>Power</kbd> and <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> together and hold them for a second.